# How do I split a byte[] image into multiple byte[] of a maximum 10000 length each byte?

Tags: java, image-processing, split, byte

I found a lot of answers here, but none of them is really what I want.

Lets say I can send an Image with a maximum 10000 of size, so if I send for example a image with 25796 I need to split the byte[] in 3, 10000 + 10000 + 5796.

So I guess I should have a method that receives a byte[] and returns a list<byte[]> am I correct?

Im using `Arrays.copyOfRange` in a cycle, but the last bytes are tricky to get (for example those 5796 in the end).

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks a lot!

edit:

I think I had success, I need to test more cases, but will do that tomorrow since im tired rn. If everything is right I will post it as an answer.

Here is what I have right now: (there is an extra method to check if the bytes match in the end)

```
public List<byte[]> byteSplitter(byte[] origin) {


    List<byte[]> byteList = new LinkedList<>();


    int splitIndex = 10000;
    int currBytes = 0;
    boolean bytesHasSameLength = false;
    while (!bytesHasSameLength) {

        if (splitIndex > origin.length) {
            splitIndex = origin.length;
            bytesHasSameLength = true;
        }

        byteList.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(origin, currBytes, splitIndex));

        currBytes = splitIndex;
        splitIndex += 10000;

    }


    return byteList;
}

public void appendByteAndCheckMatch(byte[] bytes, List<byte[]> byteList) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    for (byte[] b : byteList) {
        try {
            output.write(b);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    byte[] bytesFromList = output.toByteArray();

    System.out.println("list bytes: " + bytesFromList.length);
    System.out.println("request bytes: " + bytes.length);

    if (Arrays.equals(bytesFromList, bytes))
        System.out.println("bytes are equals");
    else
        System.out.println("bytes are different");
}
```

result:

list bytes: 25796
request bytes: 25796
bytes are equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the original array in increments of "max length" while also ensuring you don't go past the length of the array. This can be done with a single `for` loop. For example:

```java
public static List<byte[]> split(byte[] source, int maxLength) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(source);
  if (maxLength <= 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxLength <= 0");
  }

  List<byte[]> result = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int from = 0; from < source.length; from += maxLength) {
    int to = Math.min(from + maxLength, source.length);
    byte[] range = Arrays.copyOfRange(source, from, to);
    result.add(range);
  }

  return result;
}
```

That will handle any non-zero positive value for `maxLength`, even if the value is greater than or equal to the length of `source`.

Note this is copying the data from the original array into new arrays. That means the original array is effectively duplicated which may or may not be acceptable since you now consume at least twice the memory (though you may be throwing away the original). If your use case allows it, and you need to use as little memory as possible, then consider `ByteBuffer`.

```java
public static List<ByteBuffer> split(byte[] source, int maxLength) {
  return split(ByteBuffer.wrap(source), maxLength);
}

public static List<ByteBuffer> split(ByteBuffer source, int maxLength) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(source);
  if (maxLength <= 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxLength <= 0");
  }

  List<ByteBuffer> result = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int index = source.position(); index < source.limit(); index += maxLength) {
    int length = Math.min(maxLength, source.limit() - index);
    ByteBuffer slice = source.slice(index, length);
    result.add(slice);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Each `ByteBuffer` returned in the list uses the same backing data. Of course, one consequence of this is that changes to the source data can affect every buffer. Though if you want you can make the buffers read-only (keep in mind that if you wrap an array then changing the array directly also affects the buffers, and you can't make an array read-only).

Comment: Thats a pretty clever answer! thanks a lot. The way I resolved it works perfecly after testing a couple times, but your way is better than mine. thanks!

Comment: Quick follow up: Note the code as I wrote it will return an empty list if `source.length == 0` or `source.position() == source.limit()`. You may want to handle that case if the returned list should never be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it pretty easily like this. The end location is adjusted to not exceed the original size.

```
byte[] array = new byte[123039];
int bufSize = 10_000;
int end = 0;
for (int offset = 0; offset <= array.length; offset+= bufSize) {
    end+=bufSize;
    if (end >= array.length) {
        end = array.length;
    }
    byte[] arr = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, offset, end  );
    // do something with arr
}
```